# What to use instead of or (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

`if Sugar == "Yes" or "yes" or "ja" or "Ja": print(Msg1)`

How can I make this shorter instead of using a dozen of or's

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
if Sugar in ["Yes", "yes", "ja", "Ja"]:
    print(Msg1)
```